# Read values from a nested JSON formatted file in java

Tags: java, json

I'm unsure how to read the following JSON file as the nested array doesn't have a key mapped to it. I understand that using `JSONArray fileList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get(fileName);`allows me to access the first array but from here I'm stuck.

```
{
"file1_1.txt": [
   [
     "2015-08-26 12:03:44 +1200",
     "d6072668c069d40c27c3f982789b32e33f23575316ebbbc11359c49929ac8adc"
   ],
   [
     "2015-08-26 12:03:42 +1200",
     "a2ebea1d55e6059dfb7b8e8354e0233d501da9d968ad3686c49d6a443b9520a8"
   ]
 ],
"file1_2.txt": [
   [
     "2015-08-26 12:03:42 +1200",
     "c62b8de531b861db068eac1129c2e3105ab337b225339420d2627c123c7eae04"
   ]
 ],
"file2_1.txt": [
   [
     "2015-08-26 12:03:42 +1200",
     "3032e7474e22dd6f35c618045299165b0b42a9852576b7df52c1b22e3255b112"
   ]
 ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think this format matches JSON specification.

Comment: Ah apologies, it isn't a JSON file, it's JSON formatted. Is there any possible way to read it?

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray fileList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get(fileName);
JSONArray inner = fileList.getJsonArray(0);
```

You can get the number of elements with inner.size();

PS: I copy and pasted the JSON example on jsonlint.com and it showed as valid JSON format.

Comment: Thank you! Knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: Sorry, a little typo: it is getJsonArray() instead of get().

Comment: Get an error when I use getJsonArray(0)...The method getJsonArray(int) is undefined for the type JSONArray

Comment: Odd... See http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONArray(int) but looks like its signature changed on recent versions: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html#getJsonArray-int-

Comment: May I suggest something? Don't waste your time with this awkward JSON lib. Use Jackson that is a better, more intuitive and powerful JSON lib for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONObject` for your `json` format. By using `JSONObject` you can the get the keys of the `JSONObject` ex: `file1_1.txt, file1_2.txt, etc..`

Find the below code:

```
String str = " { "+
        "\"file1_1.txt\": ["+
           "["+
             "\"2015-08-26 12:03:44 +1200\","+
             "\"d6072668c069d40c27c3f982789b32e33f23575316ebbbc11359c49929ac8adc\""+
           "],"+
           "["+
             "\"2015-08-26 12:03:42 +1200\","+
             "\"a2ebea1d55e6059dfb7b8e8354e0233d501da9d968ad3686c49d6a443b9520a8\""+
           "]"+
     "],"+
        "\"file1_2.txt\": ["+
           "["+
             "\"2015-08-26 12:03:42 +1200\","+
             "\"c62b8de531b861db068eac1129c2e3105ab337b225339420d2627c123c7eae04\""+
           "]"+
         "],"+
        "\"file2_1.txt\": ["+
           "["+
            "\"2015-08-26 12:03:42 +1200\","+
           " \"3032e7474e22dd6f35c618045299165b0b42a9852576b7df52c1b22e3255b112\""+
          " ]"+
         "]"+
        "}";


    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);

    Set<String> set = obj.keySet(); 

    System.out.println(set);
```

Here I am passing your format as `String str` to 'JSONObject' and creating instance `obj`. By using `obj` I'm getting json keys from by calling `obj.keySet()` it'll returns `Set` instance, like `keySet()` method another method is there, i.e., 'keys' which returns `Iterator` instance.

Give it a try :)